# Returing an array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add two matrices using the following code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int matrix (void)
    {
        int a[2][2];
        int b[2][2];
        int c[2][2];
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                    scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                    scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                    c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
    int main ()
    {
        int i, j;
        int c[2][2];
        c = matrix();
        for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                    printf("%d", c[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Above code is throwing many errors. Please explain why so many errors are shown by my compiler.

EDIT- I used GCC 4.4.3 when compiling above code.

EDIT2 - I got following errors and warnings when compiling above code.

```
test.c: In function ‘matrix’:
test.c:23: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
test.c:23: warning: function returns address of local variable
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:29: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[2][2]’ from type ‘int’
```

Comment: And what would those errors be?

Comment: Which compiler is it?

Comment: You get a lot of warnings up front: http://ideone.com/FkqAER - mostly in treating pointers as integers.

Comment: This isn't a compile error -- it's much worse. It's a bug.  Whenever you try to print the contents of an array, you do something like this: `printf("%d", &c[i][j]);` Remove the address-of operator (`&`). You want to print what's stored in `c[i][j]`, not the address of `c[i][j]`.

Comment: The main problem is that the function returns an int when should return the matrix. That's the only compilation error I found. There are other warnings too. Apart from that there are semantic errors as well.

Comment: I down voted your question: when you have errors, you should add them to the question (or using pastebin if there's too much)  so that we don't try to guess where's the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix as what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*matrix(void))[2]{//return pointer as int (*)[2]
    static int c[2][2];//Can not be used to return the automatic local variables.
    int a[2][2];
    int b[2][2];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return c;
}
int main (){
    int i, j;
    int (*c)[2];
    c = matrix();
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", c[i][j]);//remove &
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I have respect for the original. Such prefer  to say to the OP .

Comment: They are seems to a smug opinion.

Comment: Sigh.. A smug assertion is repeated. Please understand that things needed by when and if each is different.

Comment: What is needed change in the situation. It is not decided in one this is correct. You cannot understand it. I do not have to hear your silly talk.

Comment: Perpetrators do not notice the nuisance of yourself.

Comment: Please stop the comments  to repeat relentlessly. I think annoying.

Comment: There is no need to comment when you stop me. You can not understand it. So, it is not to deal anymore. Goodbye.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you have `matrix` returning a local array of `int`s, but declared it to return a single `int` value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void matrix (int c[][2]) //Fix 1
{
    int a[2][2];
    int b[2][2];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
}
int main ()
{
    int i, j;
    int c[2][2];
    matrix(c); //Fix 2
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                printf("%d\t", c[i][j]); //Fix 3
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is IMO the best solution. The caller is responsible for the lifetime of the array, and the function matrix() only fills it. That is a proper separation of concerns. +1

Answer (score 0):

The following will not print the value:

```
printf("%d", &c[i][j]);
```

But some pointer (if it compile). You must do:

```
printf("%d", c[i][j]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your're returning 2D-Array by using return c which can only be used to return a variable having data type other than 1D or 2D-Array. To fix this, you need to return 2D-Array i.e

```
return [i][j]
```

Also, you've declared c as 2D-Array but while returning you're using it as a variable.

```
int c[2][2];
c = matrix();
```

To fix it, either use

```
c[i][j]= matrix();
```

or declare c as

```
int c;
```